# After Method: Cut String at '-' or ' '

Tags: java

The input string may contain hyphens and spaces that mark places to truncate the string. The output string will be a truncated version of the input string, and the input int value is the desired length of the output string. The output string should truncate the input string at the first legal spot so the output string will have the desired length. If the truncation happens at a space, the output does not include the space, but if the truncation happens at a hyphen, the output includes the hyphen. No other hyphens are included in the output, but the other spaces are.

How can I fix my code to get the "What code should output" output without using arrays and breaks?

```
public static String after(int length, String s1) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int x = 0;
    for(; sb.length() < length && x < s1.length() - 1; x = x + 1) {
      if(s1.charAt(x) != '-') {
        sb.append(s1.charAt(x));
      }
    }
    for(; x < sb.length() && s1.charAt(x) - 1 != '-'; x = x + 1) {
      sb.append(s1.charAt(x));
    }
    if(s1.charAt(x) == ' ' && s1.length() + 1 == s1.length()) {
      sb.append(s1.charAt(x));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Input are:

```
 HW2.after(5, "La-te-ly the-re.")
 HW2.after(6, "La-te-ly the-re.")
 HW2.after(7, "La-te-ly the-re.")
```

I am getting the output :

```
"Latel"
"Lately"
"Lately "
```

What Actually output is:

```
"Late-"
"Lately"
"Lately the-"
```

Comment: This is *still* very unclear, well at-least for me. Can you please edit your question to provide a *simplistic* example of an input and output?

Comment: ...and maybe a description of what the code is supposedly doing in general.  Have you walked through this in a debugger?  Seems that's how you'd want to figure out what's going on...just watch the code go through the logic.

Comment: The input string may contain hyphens and spaces that mark places to truncate the string. The output string will be a truncated version of the input string, and the input int value is the desired length of the output string. The output string should truncate the input string at the first legal spot so the output string will have the desired length. If the truncation happens at a space, the output does not include the space, but if the truncation happens at a hyphen, the output includes the hyphen. No other hyphens are included in the output, but the other spaces are.

Comment: You just need to keep playing with your logic.  This isn't a free programmer site.  But I'll tell you that you need to get out of the first loop earlier, so that the second loop can do something. Right now, the first loop just grabs the number of non-'-' characters you request regardless of if you end on a hyphen, and so the second loop never does anything

Comment: how HW2.truncateAfter(7, "La-te-ly the-re.") is works? because the length is more than 7.

Comment: What's the meaning of `legal spot`?

Comment: I coded this up.  It's possible without too much trouble.  This feels to me like a homework assignment, in which case giving you the answer isn't the right move.  I could help you through it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework question, so I'll just give you the approach I used, so you can think through the coding for yourself...

Stop your first loop one short of the number of requested characters.  You have to not skip spaces, but keep a count of them, and subtract that from sb.length() you're testing in your loop because your desired length excludes spaces.

Then deal with the case where you're now pointing to a space, by testing for that, and if true, adding it to the output string and advancing x.

Then keep looking at the next character and adding it to the result as long as it isn't a dash or a space.

Finally, if you stopped on a dash, add it to the output.